# p-adic valuation of a sum

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $n_1$, ..., $n_k$ denote positive integers, and let us write
$$ n_i=\prod_{j=1}^m p_j^{\alpha_{ij}}$$
for $1\le i\le k$, where the $p_j$'s are distinct prime numbers, and $\alpha_{ij}\ge 0$ for all $i$ and $j$.

Consider a sum $$N=\sum_{i=1}^k \epsilon_i n_i$$ where $\epsilon_i=\pm 1$ for all $i$.

> Can we bound the $p_j$ -adic valuation of $N$ in terms of $k$, $m$ and the $\alpha_{ij}$'s (or more precisely their logarithms)?

I am also interested in special cases, such as:

- What happens with $m=2$? Or with $k=2$? Or both $k=m=2$?
- Can we bound the $2$-adic valuation of integers of the form $1\pm 3^{\alpha_1}\pm\dots \pm 3^{\alpha_k}$, $0<\alpha_1<\dots<\alpha_k$?

[EDIT] In particular, a very special case of the latter can be proved (thanks to Gerry Myerson for his comment!):

> The maximal $2$-adic valuation of $3^n-1$ is $2+\log(n)$.

**Proof.** As mentioned at [oeis.org/A090740](http://oeis.org/A090740), one has $v_2(3^{2k+1}-1)=1$ for all $k$, and $v_2(3^{2k}-1)=v_2(3^k-1)+1+[\text{$k$ is odd}]$ where $[\text{$k$ is odd}]$ equals $1$ if $k$ is odd and $0$ otherwise. This implies  that $v_2(3^n-1)=2+v_2(n)$, whence the bound. $\square$

Comment: The power of $2$ dividing $3^n-1$ is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A090740 and you will see it follows a simple pattern.

Comment: Thanks Gerry! The OEIS gives a recurrence formula that shows that $v_2(3^n-1)=v_2(n)+2$, thus in particular $v_2(3^n-1)\le 2+\log(n)$.